# CSLA.net - Inheritable Base classes

Tags: c#, csla

I was reading the book `"Expert C# 2005 Business Objects"`.

The book describes various base classes to be inherited by various classes to solve real-world problems.

[image]

But the book does not provide examples of all those classes.

Can anyone give me all of those examples (with reason) to better understand CSLA?

For example, Which real-world objects are to be considered as Read-only Root Objects (Student/Product/Order, etc.)? And Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ProjectTracker sample (which can be downloaded on the [CSLA downloads page](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/download.aspx)) has examples of all the main sterotypes used in the CSLA books.

Chapter 6 in the book (Object Orientated Application Design) gives an overview of the design process of business objects & Chapter 8 (Business Object Implementation) gives the actual implementation of the Project Tracker objects.

In terms of your specific query - I haven't often used "Read-only root" objects. However, I often use "Read-only list root" objects though. An example would be: I have a list called ProductInfoList, which has a read-only child ProductInfo. This would be returned to the user either in a ListBox, or from a search result, etc.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find what you need:

http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/download.aspx (see Framework, test, samples)

But before that take a look at this article:

[The CSLA Framework; what is in it for me?](http://www.primos.com.au/primos/Portals/0/Tech%20articles/CSLA%20WIIFM/What%20could%20CSLA%20do%20for%20me.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend checking out our [CSLA 3.8 templates](http://code.google.com/p/codesmith/downloads/list). I had this same dilemma when I was learning CSLA. He does provide sample snippets of what each BO Type should look like but I don't find this very helpful to visualize. You could take a look at our templates and [run the quick start](http://community.codesmithtools.com/blogs/videotutorials/archive/2009/07/13/csla-the-quick-start.aspx) against one of your databases that you are familiar with and modify the different BO Types per table to get a better understanding of how CSLA works.